# Entry name 'classes.dex' collided

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

While trying to Generate a signed APK I'm getting this error

```
Entry name 'classes.dex' collided
```

Can someone tell me how to solve it? I recently changed the default package name which was com.exmaple to my app's name. It builds correctly but gives this error while trying to generate a signed APK

My android studio version is 4.1.2

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You are probably facing this error because you already have a signed APK in your project's "release" folder. Please check for any existing APK and delete it, then try to generate once more.

Comment: I think this will go down in history as one of the most misleading error messages of all time. - Your solution works like a charm ;)

Comment: this is the second time I am here, for different android studio versions, buld failed with the same message `Entry name 'classes.dex' collided `same cause `app-release.apk` is already in the `release` folder

Comment: I'm surprised they haven't fixed this yet

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem and here's how I solved it easily:

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK..

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in build.gradle

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'classes.dex'
    exclude '**.**'
    }
}
```

https://rtdevs.xyz/how-to-solve-entry-name-classes-dex-collided-in-android-studio/