# Error - Zip file app-debug.apk already contains entry 'classes.dex', cannot overwrite

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-support-library, android-library

I imported a jar file in app/libs dir and added it as a library in build.gradle file. But when I am building the project getting errors -

```
Zip file 'E:\AndroidProjects\testing\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'classes.dex', cannot overwrite
```

Note - This jar file is created in another environment/ having a different signature.

```
implementation files('libs/myjar.jar')
```

This issue looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763776/zip-file-app-build-intermediates-app-classes-release-classes-jar-already-contai) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477093/entry-name-classes-dex-collided) -  and I have tried deleting/ cleaning the build folder but this error is not going away. I also tried changing the Gradle version to the latest 7.2.1.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error too.
In my case i tried to add a jar file to my app containing a classes.dex file.
I could avoid that error by adding the lib compiled to java byte code rather than dex bytecode.

Comment: Well, in my case I can't control this behavior. Because this jar is created by some 3rd party people. I am not sure if a .jar file can also have java byte code and dex bytecode differently.

Comment: you could try to decompile the dex file back to java byte code like in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode